# How do you move a CALayer instantly (without animation)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-animation, calayer

I'm trying to drag a `CALayer` in an iOS app.

As soon as I change its position property it tries to animate to the new position and flickers all over the place:

```
 layer.position = CGPointMake(x, y)
```

How can I move `CALayers` instantly? I can't seem to get my head around the Core Animation API.

Comment: **regarding this extremely old QA, the critical issue today is this:**  https://stackoverflow.com/a/56980329/294884

Answer (score 174, accepted):

You want to wrap your call in the following:

```
[CATransaction begin]; 
[CATransaction setValue: (id) kCFBooleanTrue forKey: kCATransactionDisableActions];
layer.position = CGPointMake(x, y);
[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: That's exactly it. I didn't even think of the CATransaction. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yup, 6 and a half years later. Still helpful. :D

Comment: iOS7 supports new shorthand: `[UIView performWithoutAnimation:<#^(void)actionsWithoutAnimation#>];`

Comment: 7 and a half years later, Still helpful.

Comment: 7 years, 7 months, and 17 days later: still helpful. Thanks!

Comment: thumb up 9 years later

Comment: Yes!! thumbs up 9 years later!

Comment: guys @vilanovi etc, 12 years later it's wrong  :)  these days, you do this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/56980329/294884

Answer (score 38):

Swift 3 Extension :

```
extension CALayer {
    class func performWithoutAnimation(_ actionsWithoutAnimation: () -> Void){
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setValue(true, forKey: kCATransactionDisableActions)
        actionsWithoutAnimation()
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
CALayer.performWithoutAnimation(){
    someLayer.position = newPosition
}
```

Comment: It's useful to add the `@noescape` attribute to the block to allow (and make it clear) that `self` is not needed in the block

Answer (score 24):

You can also use the convenience function

```
[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES]
```

as well.

Note: Be sure to read the comments by Yogev Shelly to understand any gotchas that could occur.

Comment: Important, this effects all CALayer so you want to reenable actions after you're done, i.e [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES]

Comment: Damn I should have said that. Good save. The command disables animations until it is set to NO or until the core graphics animation engine has completed a run cycle. Not sure if that's the right word for it :/ But Thank you for clearing that up for everybody.

Answer (score 15):

As others have suggested, you can use `CATransaction`.
The problem comes arises because CALayer has a default implicit animation duration of 0.25 seconds.

Thus, an easier (in my opinion) alternative to `setDisableActions` is to use `setAnimationDuration` with a value of `0.0`.

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:0.0];
layer.position = CGPointMake(x, y);
[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: Easy to remember, easy to understand when you're re-reading the code, and easier to type.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Combining previous answers here for Swift 4, to clearly make the animation duration explicit...

```
extension CALayer
{
    class func perform(withDuration duration: Double, actions: () -> Void) {
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(duration)
        actions()
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
}
```

Usage...

```
CALayer.perform(withDuration: 0.0) {
            aLayer.frame = aFrame
        }
```