# Add a sublayer to a CALayer without animation?

Tags: objective-c, core-animation, calayer

How can I add a sublayer to a **CALayer** without animation? Usually when you add one it "*fades in*" and when you remove one it "fades out".

***How to supress the animation?***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue
                 forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
[layer addSublayer:sublayer];
[CATransaction commit];
```

from [the Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Transactions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006096-SW6)?

Comment: This should work, but note that as of iPhone OS 3.0 you can simply do [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];

Comment: Yep. Good point. Wish we could get an update to the Apple docs. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can also suppress implicit layer addition animations by setting the actions dictionary on the superlayer, like I describe in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133547/unable-to-disable-animation-of-calayerremovefromsuperlayer/3136478#3136478):

```
NSMutableDictionary *newActions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNull null], @"sublayers", nil];
superlayer.actions = newActions;
[newActions release];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:0.0f];
```

Comment: please use a word like "can" instead of "need" when there are other available solutions that don't *need* to do it