# CATransition push without fade

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-animation

I'm making a navigation controller class for Mac OS X.

I want to replace the current view with a `kCATransitionPush` animation.
Like in this post:
[Core Animation Tutorial - Wizard Dialog With Transitions](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/03/03/core-animation-tutorial-wizard-dialog-with-transitions/)

The `CATransition` is set up like this:

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
[self.view setAnimations:@{ @"subviews" : transition }];
```

---

However, when I replace the views, there is a fade animation, which is being automatically added.

```
[NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
{
    [[self.view animator] replaceSubview:_currentViewController.view with:newViewController.view];
}
[NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
```

---

How can I do a push animation without the fading?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way I've found to get smooth Core Animation transitions that works regardless of whether the view supports CA or not is to do the following:

1. Create an image of the view you are trying to animate, using `NSView -cacheDisplayInRect:toBitmapImageRep` or a similar method
2. Put that image in an NSImageView
3. Layer back the image view, which will draw fine without glitches when layer backed
4. Add the image view as a subview *over* the view that you are trying to transition
5. Animate the image view frame using NSView's animator proxy
6. Remove the image view once the animation has completed

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're running into implicit animations - Core Animation will automatically animate layer property changes that happen outside of your own transactions.

There's a good summary of several methods for disabling these implicit animations in these two questions:

[How to disable CALayer implicit animations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833488/how-to-disable-calayer-implicit-animations)

[Disabling implicit animations in -[CALayer setNeedsDisplayInRect:]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244147/disabling-implicit-animations-in-calayer-setneedsdisplayinrect)

...and you can read more about implicit transactions [in the Core Animation docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Transactions.html)

Comment: I'm not really sure if I get what you mean. I tried it with `CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    [transition setValue:(id)kCFBooleanFalse
                     forKey:kCATransitionFade];` but it didn't work, no error message, just the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I think the transition from left transition includes a built-in fade. The IOS push transitions do.

If you don't want that, you might have to roll your own push transition using Core Animation. This would be easy in iOS with UIView animations. Sadly, there is not an equivalent in Mac OS. I wish Apple would go back and add view animations to Mac OS. I get spoiled using them in iOS, and then miss them when I work on Mac applications.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code

```
        CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
        transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
        [transition setDuration:0.5];
        [self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
```