# How to optionally animate property of a CALayer with custom animation

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I have a CALayer with a custom animation on it, working via an `@NSManaged` property, and overriding:

- `class func defaultValue(forKey key: String) -> Any?`
- `class func needsDisplay(forKey key: String) -> Bool`
- `func action(forKey key: String) -> CAAction?`
- `func display()`

However, I sometimes want to bypass the animation and have the property immediately step to the new value. In my `CALayer` sub-class I tried this:

```
@NSManaged private var radius: CGFloat

func animate(to radius: CGFloat) {
    self.radius = radius
}

func step(to radius: CGFloat) {
    // Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/34941743
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)   // Prevents animation occurring
    self.radius = radius
    CATransaction.commit()
    setNeedsDisplay()                       // Has no effect
}
```

When `animate(to:)` is called, `display()` is called repeatedly and my custom drawing code can do it's thing. When `step(to:)` is called, the `CATransaction` code does prevent an animation from occurring, but no drawing is ever performed at all.

I *can* get it to behave as desired, but it feels quite hacky:

```
func step(to radius: CGFloat) {
    // func action(forKey key: String) -> CAAction? uses .animationDuration
    // when constructing a CABasicAnimation
    let duration = animationDuration
    defer { animationDuration = duration }
    animationDuration = 0
    self.radius = radius
}
```

What is the correct method to give the caller the ability to choose whether the property animates from one value to the next, or steps immediately? A subsequent change to `radius` should respect the previous value, whether it was stepped or animated to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you have implemented `action(forKey:)` (quite rightly). So on those occasions when you don't want this property to be animated, return `nil` from that method. The drawing will still take place, but without animation.

Alternatively, you could return `super.action(forKey:key)`. That might be a little more sane, but the outcome is the same.

---

You may ask (and I hope you do): How can I throw some kind of switch that `action(forKey:)` can consult in order to know which kind of occasion this is? One possibility is to set a property of the layer using key-value coding.

CALayer has a wonderful feature that you are allowed to call `setValue(_:forKey:)` or `value(forKey:)` for any key; it doesn't have to be a "real" key that already exists.

So you could call `setValue(false, forKey:"shouldAnimate")` on the layer before setting the property. And your `action(forKey:)` can then consult `value(forKey:"shouldAnimate")`, and see whether it is `false` (as opposed to `true` or `nil`)  — and if it is, it returns `nil` to prevent the animation.

Comment: Done, thanks. Is there an advantage/circumstance that makes `setValue(_:forKey:)` better than simply exposing a regular property on my `CALayer` subclass?