# How to prevent animations when changing CAGradientLayer properties in a clean way

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I want to prevent animations occuring when changing CAGradientLayer properties such as the colors.
I found this:
[Why changing values of a CAGradientLayer causes an "automatic" animation? And how can I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14163819/why-changing-values-of-a-cagradientlayer-causes-an-automatic-animation-and-ho)

Seems like we are using a crowbar to open a beer can , is there not a way to do this without constantly wrapping the changes in dead animation calls? A cleaner way?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to David, I figured it out.

```
-(id<CAAction>) actionForLayer:(CALayer *)layer forKey:(NSString *)event {
    if(layer == self.mylayer) {
        return (id<CAAction>)[NSNull null];
    }
    return nil;
}
```