# UITableViewCell label displayed with little slide up animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I am displaying list of persons in a tableView. On clicking any of the cell, app displays a new screen. When user comes back to previous screen, a tableView should appear. Here, when user comes back to screen with tableView, I call server API to get updated list of people and reload table to display them.

The issue is when user comes back to screen and tableView is displayed, label in `UITableViewCell` is animated a little bit. This animation is such that label moves from some place below its correct position and animation upwards to its correct position. This animation is not implemented by me, neither do I want it. Its visible for around 0.5-1 sec.

Compare below label's position before and after animation.

[image][image]

Has anyone experienced this?

**Note :** *Note that I have used autolayout. Which might be an issue because before using autolayout this issue was not there.*

**Edit :** Tried to disable implicit animation as shown below but not working.

```
NSMutableDictionary *newActions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNull null], @"onOrderIn",
                                   [NSNull null], @"onOrderOut",
                                   [NSNull null], @"sublayers",
                                   [NSNull null], @"contents",
                                   [NSNull null], @"bounds",
                                   nil];
cell.textLabel.layer.actions = newActions;
cell.detailTextLabel.layer.actions = newActions;
cell.layer.actions = newActions;
cell.contentView.layer.actions = newActions;
```

Comment: Where/how do you set the label's position? Whats happing is probably some implicit animation

Comment: @rist Yes, some implicit animation. But not getting why. I don't set label's position because it is default cell implementation. I don't subclass it.

Comment: @Geek what type of cell you have used? UITableViewCellStyleDefault? or any other one.

Comment: @NagaMalleshMaddali I use `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle`.

Comment: It sounds like some missing or conflicting Auto Layout constraints - or maybe a priority got set wrong. Could you share more of your Auto Layout setup for the cell?

Comment: Why don't you try to use custom cell?

Comment: @anum90 That would be the last resort.

Comment: Maybe you can try disabling the implicit animations of the label. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244147/disabling-implicit-animations-in-calayer-setneedsdisplayinrect

Comment: @JackWu Not working. Tried as added in edited question.

Comment: @Geek Inside the "NewActions", add two lines for @"position" and @"center"

Comment: @JackWu Tried. Did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue. Sorry to bother you guys. It was so silly. I was refreshing the table when user comes back from next view controller by calling REST API and then calling a method `displayTable` which displays a table from bottom.
Now, I call `reloadData` method to refresh it if its already displayed, instead of calling `displayTable`.