# How to change a CALayer's default animation time?

Tags: iphone, core-animation, calayer

I use these code to move a CALayer:

```
CGPoint position = self.position;
position.x += 10;
position.y += 10;
self.position = position;
```

There is a default animation when i change the position of a layer without any animation call.This will cause lag on movement of a layer when i use these code in touchesMoved:withEvent:.

What i want to do is remove the default animation, and move the layer immediately so that it can responds to touch event quickly, just like the "center" property of UIView does.

What should i do? special thx!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling implicit animations in -\[CALayer setNeedsDisplayInRect:\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244147/disabling-implicit-animations-in-calayer-setneedsdisplayinrect)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The other poster had the right idea, but didn't provide enough information.

If you want to change layer properties instantly, without animation, you need to put those changes inside a CATransaction where you disable actions:

```
[CATransaction begin];
//[CATransaction setAnimationDuration: 1.0/30.0];
[CATransaction setDisableActions: TRUE];
//Put layer changes you want to take place without animation here.
[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: Why set an non-zero animation duration if we don't want any animation ?

Comment: Because I didn't think about it enough before typing my answer. You're right that the duration has no point. (I commented that bit out in my answer. Thanks for pointing that out.)

Answer (score 1):

Simply set

```
 [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
```

this will make the Layer move without lag