# NSAttributed String with CATextLayer inside a UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsattributedstring, catextlayer

My requirement is parts of text should be displayed as bold and colored within each cell of a UITableview. I have managed it using the NSMutableAttributedString, CATextLayer and cell's contenview's layer. Below is the code that i have used to display.

```
 CATextLayer *textLayer = nil;   //used to draw the attributed string
 CALayer *layer = nil; 
    if(cell == nil) {
                 textLayer = [[CATextLayer alloc] init];
                textLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
                [textLayer setForegroundColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
                [textLayer setContentsScale:[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]];
                textLayer.wrapped = YES;
                layer = cell.contentView.layer;
                [layer addSublayer:textLayer];
                textLayer = nil;
    }
//get the layer by nesting sublayer of cell layer because we don't have tag property for the layer and textlayer.


if (!layer) {
       layer = cell.contentView.layer;
   }



for (id subLayer in layer.sublayers) {
            if ([subLayer isKindOfClass:[CATextLayer class]]) {
                // NSLog(@"found textlayer");
                textLayer = subLayer;
                textLayer.string = nil;
            }
        }
textLayer.frame = CGRectMake(53.0f, 23.0f, 240.0f, attributedStrHeight);

        if([self isNotNull:mAttrbtdStr]) {
            textLayer.string = mAttrbtdStr;
        }
```

The Problem is when I scroll the table fast the text is displaying as animated(Overlapping), and after stopped scrolling it is displaying properly. Please find the below reference image

[image: Overlapping AttributedString While Table Scrolling Fast]

Could any one please help me why this overlapping is happening only when i scroll the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is really an interesting question, `CALayer` properties are animated by default(implicit animation) so it could be the default behavior of the `CATextLayer` inside the scrollview animation. One solution could be disable them, you have two options:

1. DIsable animation in current transaction, but I don't how this could affect normal animation on tableview even if you are creating a new transaction

   `[CATransaction begin];`

   `[CATransaction setValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES] forKey: kCATransactionDisableActions];`

   `[CATransaction commit];`
2. Setting the animation action dictionary the return null, here's a help [Disabling implicit animations in -[CALayer setNeedsDisplayInRect:]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244147/disabling-implicit-animations-in-calayer-setneedsdisplayinrect)

Comment: Thanks Andrea, the second solution worked for me. Below is the code i have used to fix it. NSMutableDictionary *newActions = NSMutableDictionary *newActions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNull null], @"onOrderIn",
                                   [NSNull null], @"onOrderOut",
                                   [NSNull null], @"sublayers",
                                   [NSNull null], @"contents",
                                   [NSNull null], @"bounds",
                                   nil];
layer.actions = newActions;
[newActions release];

Comment: NSMutableDictionary *newActions = NSMutableDictionary *newActions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNull null], @"onOrderIn",[NSNull null], @"onOrderOut",[NSNull null], @"sublayers",[NSNull null], @"contents",[NSNull null], @"bounds",[NSNUll null],@"position",[NSNUll null], @"hidden",nil];
layer.actions = newActions;