# What is the best best way to disable cross fades on UICollectionView/UICollectionViewLayout rotates or bounds changes?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uicollectionview

I have a subclass of `UICollectionViewLayout` which places cells in a circle. The layout returns `YES` for the call `shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:`. On rotation, the cell in the initial position fades out and the cell in the final position fades in.

By adding the following code to my layout I can disable the fades and the
circle of items appears to to simply rotate with the orientation change:

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)itemIndexPath {
    return nil;
}

- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)itemIndexPath {
    return [self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:itemIndexPath];
}
```

Why do the methods get called on a bounds change because documentation doesn't seem to suggest they do? Documentation seems to state they get called related to insertion and removal of items from the collection view.

Is there a better way to disable the cross fade during rotation?

Notes:

- The `initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:` documentation
  states that by default the method returns `nil` but calls to `super` returned
  non-nil values.
- I set symbolic breakspoints on the `UICollectionView` methods
  `deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:`, `moveItemAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` and
  `insertItemsAtIndexPaths:` and none of them are hit during rotation.

Comment: This is just a shot in the dark, but for the disabling of the rotation animation, you could shut off core animation entirely for the rotation operation: [CATransaction begin];
        [CATransaction setValue:(id) kCFBooleanFalse forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
        // do your rotation
        [CATransaction commit];

Comment: Maybe, internally on a bounds change the items get removed and added and as a result the methods get called. As for why -deleteItemsAtIndexPaths: and -insertItemsAtIndexPaths: don't get called.. no clue here. Perhaps the UIKit programmer cheated and avoided the API to perform the insert and delete? Not unprecedented.

Comment: Could you disable the implicit animations on the view's backing layer using something like I describe here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244147/disabling-implicit-animations-in-calayer-setneedsdisplayinrect/2244734#2244734 ?

Comment: Your question inadvertently answered a problem I've had for the last couple years w/UICollectionView crossfades.  Thank you, you made my week!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `UICollectionViewLayout.h` file states

```
// This set of methods is called when the collection view undergoes an
     animated transition such as a batch update block or an animated 
     bounds change.
// For each element on screen before the invalidation, 
     finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingXXX will be called and an 
     animation setup from what is on screen to those final attributes.
// For each element on screen after the invalidation, 
     initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingXXX will be called an an 
     animation setup from those initial attributes to what ends up on 
     screen.
```

which clearly says they are called on bounds changes. Rather than removal/insertion, "old state" and "new state" seems more accurate.