# UICollectionView not animating bound change

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a `UICollectionView` in `UISplitViewController` with a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` which implements:

- `prepareLayout` to store the attributes with right frames (based on orientation);
- `collectionViewContentSize` to return the right collection view size based on the orientation
- `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath` just returns the stored attributes
- `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` check for the intersections

My layout looks like this in portrait mand landscape mode:

[image: Portrait]        [image: Landscape]

Now, the problem is that when I change the orientation of the screen, I use this function to trigger the layout update:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
    [headlinesCollectionView performBatchUpdates:nil completion:nil];
}
```

and this changes instantly the cell frame size to the new one; however the cell position get animated. Before trying this I used `invalidateLayout`, which does even a worse job since it doesn't animate either the size or the position.

Any idea on how I could make this work? The cell should get resized AND move whilst the animation occurs.

Comment: Layout has a method that you can override, something like invalidateLayoutOnBoundsChange:

Comment: @Andy The layout gets invalidated and re-drawn correctly. The problem is that the cells snaps to the new size instead of gracefully animating.

Comment: Try implementing https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionViewLayout/shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:

Comment: And stop manual invalidation on rotation

Comment: I followed your instructions and if the bounds change, that method return now YES and the transaction occurs. However, the cells are not resized, they merely cross-fade. :(

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/a/12834768/351305