# Within CALayer, drawInContext: is called but does not update screen

Tags: cocoa, calayer, quartz-2d

I am trying to draw a custom CALayer which is then added as a sublayer elsewhere.  The custom CALayer class only has one variable:

```
float xScale = 0.5f;
```

And overrides the `drawInContext:` method:

```
    -(void) drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {

        NSLog(@"Method called with xScale %f", xScale);

        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [NSColor redColor].CGColor);
        CGContextAddRect(ctx, CGRectMake(100 * xScale, 100, 50, 50));
        CGContextFillPath(ctx);
    }
```

To draw a red square on the screen.  When the class is initialised in a NSView elsewhere with:

```
heartLayer = [[HeartCALayer alloc] init];
heartLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
[self.layer addSublayer:heartLayer];
[heartLayer setNeedsDisplay];
```

The square is drawn in the correct place.  However when I then ask the layer to redraw with

```
heartLayer.xScale = 1.0f;
[heartLayer setNeedsDisplay];
```

The `drawInContext:` method is called, and the `xScale` variable is updated, but the square doesn't change it's location.  I don't know why the screen is not updating.  Is it something to do with the CALayer being added as a sublayer?  Is the graphics context invalid somehow? Is it related to the implicit animation of CALayers?  I've searched everywhere and am at my wits end :(

Thanks,  Kenneth

---

Sorry to answer my own question: perhaps you'll waste less time than me:

The problem was the implicit animation of the CALayer class.  This is discussed in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244147/disabling-implicit-animations-in-calayer-setneedsdisplayinrect).

I added the following override method to the custom CALayer class:

```
- (id<CAAction>)actionForLayer:(CALayer *)layer forKey:(NSString *)key {
    return (id)[NSNull null];
}
```

and my square updated correctly.