# Disabling CALayer implicit animations

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-animation, calayer

The class below is attempting to stop any implicit animations from occurring when a `CALayer` has a property changed.

```
// NoImplicitAnimations.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface NoImplicitAnimations : NSObject

- (id<CAAction>) actionForLayer:(CALayer *)layer forKey:(NSString *)key;

@end



// NoImplicitAnimations.m

#import "NoImplicitAnimations.h"

@implementation NoImplicitAnimations

- (id<CAAction>) actionForLayer:(CALayer *)layer forKey:(NSString *)key {
  return (id)[NSNull null];
}

@end
```

I import `NoImplicitAnimations.h` in my Objective-C to Swift bridging header.

I create a global constant `let _noImplicitAnimations = NoImplicitAnimations()`.

I extend the `CALayer` class like so:

```
extension CALayer {
  func noImplicitAnimations () {
    delegate = _noImplicitAnimations
  }
}
```

Now comes the problem. I use `myLayer.noImplicitAnimations()` right after I create `myLayer`. Yet, implicit animations are still happening.

#### What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. This actually does work. I was testing it on the wrong `CALayer`. My bad!