# Update CALayer sublayers immediately

Tags: ios, swift, calayer

I have UIView which has the following structure:

```
UIView
  |- layer (CALayer)
    |- depthLayer (CALayer)
    |- bodyLayer (CALayer)
```

For *layer* I set needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = true. When I change size of UIView, *layer* redraws immediately. But their sublayers updates with some delay (on the next draw iteration). How to sync draw of *layers* with sublayers *depthLayer* and *bodyLayer*?

UIView:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    bodyLayer.frame = rect
    depthLayer.frame = CGRectOffset(rect, 0, 5)
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you try to override the setFrame method and set all the frames inside there, Also please note that CALayers will try to animate the Frame Change with key frame animation (Or whatever it called)--> To disable the animations you should refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226354/how-do-you-move-a-calayer-instantly-w-o-animation

Comment: Thanks!
I just wrapped frame updates in drawRect: with CATransaction.

Comment: You are welcome sir :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The delays you see in your `CALayer's frames` are cause because the
Animations -> when you making a change to the `CALayer's` appearance 
It tries to animate it (and it often successes -> well this is why they called animations layers).

To disable this behavior (animations) you should call the disable transactions like this:

`CATransaction.setValue(kCFBooleanTrue, forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions)
//..Make Change to the frames here
CATransaction.commit()`

Also I don't know wether you have a real need to override the `drawRect`
for this matter -> if you set the `UIView's` Frame via `setFrame:` method,
it is better to override the `setFrame:` method itself and adjust the Frames of subLayers there.

Lot of Luck!

Comment: I don't use _setFrame:_ method I think, UIView size updated by updating Auto Layout constraint. I just wanted to simplify my question, that's why I didn't mention it in the question. Tell me if I'm wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure :-) Just said in case that you doing it with setFrame,
it would be more sufficient ;-)

Comment: Also I am not sure if AutoLayout calls setFrame - you can check it by overriding the setFrame and putting a print there -> then tell me so i will know too :)

Comment: Works very well! I have written the following
CATransation.setValue....
//here I add the sublayer
CATransaction.commit()